# How to match a string between two boundaries when only one or none may be present using a regex

Tags: regex

I want to match for any string of characters between two words ("Hello" and "Goodbye" in the following examples) using a regex.

The bolded areas in the following list should match:

- Hello**, I like you.** Goodbye.
- Hello **there, do you enjoy golf?**
- **I like you.** Goodbye. See you later.

Examples of strings that should not match at all include (basically I want to treat the words "Hello" and "Goodbye" as a kind of barrier):

- HelloGoodbye
- Goodbye, how are you?
- How are you? Hello

I tried using `(?<=Hello).*(?=Goodbye)`, which works in some cases (see [here](https://i.ibb.co/MStrjj7/image.png)). The issue with this regex is that if for example "Goodbye" isn't present, none of the text after "Hello" matches (and vice versa).

I'm not exactly sure that the regex I have tried is a good way to go about it. Possibly, I just need to match any part of the string that follows "Hello" and/or preceeds "Goodbye" (but neither *need* to be present for a match).

I believe I need to have some kind of conditional, and I guess matching the first two is easy but I am unable to find a way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated as I am still new to using regular expressions.

Comment: Why not simply do `anystring` as the regex?

Comment: Is it that the *only* other text in the input may be "Hello" or "Goodbye"? ie so "Hello anystring world" does *not* match?

Comment: @JulioGB who needs regex? just test if the string *contains* "anystring".

Comment: @Bohemian I'm sorry I didnt explain it correctly, I edited the questino now. I meant anystring could literally be any string of characters, except for Hello and Goodbye. For example "Hello this is a test" would match "this is a test".

Comment: Your question is no clearer. All you have done is change "anystring" to "any string here", which changes nothing. Perhaps start by explaining how testing if the string contains `any string here` would not work for all cases. Provide some examples of input that should and should not match.

Comment: @Bohemian, if you would support my re-open vote, I would like to try and answer the question. Even though the specification is not 100% clear, I think that since the last edit there is enough information for an attempt to answer.

Comment: @kriegaex OP has neither clarified the question nor answered questions in my previous comment. IMHO the question doesn’t make sense, so it’s still not ready to answer.

Comment: @Bohemian, please only speak for yourself. I think I understand enough already.

Comment: @kriegaex so, is the solution other than the regex just being `any string here` (or `.*any string here.*` depending on your context)? If not, please explain why.

Comment: If you would be so kind as to review the examples in the question, I think you would probably understand that there could be any text in between those two boundary words. There is still some fuzziness with regard to edge cases, but for me there is enough information to try and answer the question. BTW, the linked off screenshot also helps explain the OP's intent a bit more. Like I said, the specification is not 100% clear, but let's try and help that guy anyway, guiding him to write better questions next time, shall we? He is clearly a beginner and even admitted to it.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/Nb7Wu4/1) working for you?

Comment: @Toto, you should have written an answer instead of a comment. Now someone else's answer with an almost identical solution got accepted and the OP didn't even give you any credit. But I want to do so here and now. :-) BTW, I also had an answer (simpler and using a lazy/reluctant quantifier at one point) prepared 2 days ago already, waited for the previously closed question to be unlocked, which took a while, and now see it answered already. C'est la vie! ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex: The question wasn't reopened when I quit. As you said “C'est la vie!”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=Hello|^)(?:(?!Hello|Goodbye).)+(?=Goodbye|$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Au6faC/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hello                    'Hello'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Hello                    'Hello'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Goodbye                  'Goodbye'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Goodbye                  'Goodbye'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work fine! Very clean and easy to understand.

Comment: That's nice to copy my comment and give an answer without mention.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, not quite as sophisticated as the accepted answer and matching differently in case of repetitive boundary words "Hello" and "Goodbye", but maybe a bit easier to understand because it just uses a lazy/reluctant quantifier `*?` for the match and does not resort to look-behind or look-ahead:

```
^(?:.*Hello)?(.*?)(?:Goodbye.*)?$
```

The non-capturing groups starting with `(?:` make sure that group 1 matches what you need. If you do not mind using group 2, you do not need to use non-capturing groups at all. Keep it simple! Then the regex would read:

```
^(.*Hello)?(.*?)(Goodbye.*)?$
```

You can test the first regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/cu8iu2/2).

See also this [regex quantifier cheat sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet).